# how to extract year, tz-convert and get millisecond part from a nanotime timestamp?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate, nanotime

I am using the amazing `nanotime` package to store my precious timestamps. Consider this:

```
    library(tibble)
    library(nanotime)

tibble(mytimestamp =  c(nanotime('2011-12-05 08:30:00.000',format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E9S",  tz ="GMT"),
                        nanotime('2011-12-05 08:30:00.100',format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E9S",  tz ="GMT"),
                        nanotime('2011-12-05 08:30:00.825',format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E9S",  tz ="GMT"))) 
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  mytimestamp                        
  <S4: nanotime>                     
1 2011-12-05T08:30:00.000000000+00:00
2 2011-12-05T08:30:00.100000000+00:00
3 2011-12-05T08:30:00.825000000+00:00
```

However, I do not know what is the proper syntax to

- extract the millisecond part from my timestamps
- round to the closest second (like `lubridate::floor_date(., '1 seconds')`)
- convert to a different timezone (say `'US/Eastern'`)

Do I have to use another package to do these things? For instance, using `lubridate` will lose the millisecond precision (note the .0999 instead of .100)

```
mydf %>% 
  mutate(lubritime = lubridate::as_datetime(mytimestamp))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  mytimestamp                         lubritime                
  <S4: nanotime>                      <dttm>                   
1 2011-12-05T08:30:00.000000000+00:00 2011-12-05 08:30:00.00000
2 2011-12-05T08:30:00.100000000+00:00 2011-12-05 08:30:00.09999
3 2011-12-05T08:30:00.825000000+00:00 2011-12-05 08:30:00.82500
```

Similarly, directly converting to `EST` is not allowed

```
> mydf %>% 
+   mutate(mytimestamp_EST = lubridate::with_tz(mytimestamp, 'US/Eastern'))
Error in UseMethod("reclass_date", orig) : 
  no applicable method for 'reclass_date' applied to an object of class "c('nanotime', 'integer64', 'oldClass')"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged `rcpp`?

Comment: @duckmayr sorry I can remove the tag if you like

Comment: @akrun I am worried `lubridate` wont work well with `nanotime`. Arent they storing the timestamps in a completely different way?

Comment: See the [`anytime`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=anytime) package

Comment: @coatless I looked at it, but I dont see any function that does the things I mentioned. Am I overlooking something obvious here?

Comment: yeah, it is integer64

Comment: edited the question for more clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do all of this with `data.table` because *it is known that `data.table` supports the underlying `bit64` package and `integer64` representation* that is needed here.  Other containers do not.

#### Code

```
library(nanotime)
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(ts =  c(nanotime('2011-12-05 08:30:00.000',format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E9S",  tz ="GMT"),
                         nanotime('2011-12-05 08:30:00.700',format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E9S",  tz ="GMT"),
                          nanotime('2011-12-05 08:30:00.825',format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E9S",  tz ="GMT")))
DT[, pt := as.POSIXct(ts)]
DT[, millis := as.numeric(pt - trunc(pt)) * 1e3]
```

#### Result

```
R> DT
                                    ts                      pt millis
1: 2011-12-05T08:30:00.000000000+00:00 2011-12-05 02:30:00.000      0
2: 2011-12-05T08:30:00.700000000+00:00 2011-12-05 02:30:00.700    700
3: 2011-12-05T08:30:00.825000000+00:00 2011-12-05 02:30:00.825    825
R>
```

Timezone shifts are a different (and misunderstood) topic. You can do it to `POSIXct`.

Note that all you have done here / asked for here was the millisecond resolution.  So far no need was demonstrated for `nanotime`.  But what I showed you can work on nanoseconds -- I use it every day from `data.table`.

Comment: thanks! What I like is that the printing of the timestamps is correct. Please see my edited question (the 100 millisecond timestamp prints correctly with nanotime but not with lubridate). So what you recommend for shifting time zones is to convert to `POSIXct` and then do the conversion?

Comment: Formatted content should not be confused with stored content.  When `data.table` prints nanotime it uses UTC by default.  Unless told otherwise the UTC time because local in POSIXct -- Central for me.   None of that has anything to do with `nanotime` and is standard R behaviour.

Comment: thanks and sorry if I am still a bit confused. Let say I want to convert the UTC nanotime to EST (in a different column of the data.table). How can I do that?

Comment: There is no such thing as "converting".  An UTC timestamp is an absolute record.  You can _format_ it to _character_ given a timezome attribute.  You can also _shift_ from one TZ to another (see by `RcppCCTZ` package used by `nanotime`).

Comment: thanks for the clarification again. Yes, I am interested in format the timestamp into a character with a different timezone attribute. Regarding the timeshift, running `mydf %>% mutate(other = toTz(mytimestamp, 'UTC','US/Eastern', verbose = TRUE))` creates come crazy output that I think is related to the container issue you mentioned. Is that right? thanks again!! so useful

Comment: regarding the first point, I have tried to use `mydf %>% mutate(other = strftime(mytimestamp))` but this (for `2011-12-05T08:30:00.100000000+00:00`) returns the character `2011-12-05 03:30:00.099` with the wrong millisecond part?! Do you see an easy solution here? Thanks for making all this clear for everyone.

Comment: Perhaps this is worth another question. I accept this and create a new one